# Are below mentioned packages treated as windows specific dependencies in .net project?

Tags: .net, wpf

My web application is using below packages,

```
System.Security.Principal.Windows
WindowsAzure.Storage
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
System.windows.forms
```

this particular application also has .resx files resource files
It does not have .xaml files,

**Reason behind asking this question is :**
while migrating to .net6 using upgrade assistant automatically migrated to WPF and so it added Target framework as .net6.0-windows and output type as .exe.
Do you think above mentioned are windows-specific dependencies, which caused to migrate webapplication to wpf and output type as exe?

What to check or clarification needed, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Because of above references only it is migrated WPF. At the time of migration I removed them and was able to successfully migrate to .net Core/.net 6/.net 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want your web application to be compiled as a wpf app, that's for sure.

```
 System.windows.forms
```

Is winforms and usually you'd see that in a winforms desktop app.  Ideally, only in a winforms desktop app but I guess someone wanted to use some class and they found it in there.

These are azure and hence web.

```
 WindowsAzure.Storage
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
```

This is to do with the user's AD account.

```
 System.Security.Principal.Windows
```

I guess your web app is or was using a technique called impersonation where the  controllers or webforms run in the context of the user. You could then check the user name and use their credentials for database access.  Not advisable in any substantial web app nowadays.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

I would first check these dll are used in your original app.

Take a copy to experiment with if it's not under source control.

Remove a reference which looks like it shouldn't be in a web app:

```
 System.windows.forms
```

See what errors when you compile it.

Then consider what web friendly approach you might use instead of whatever's in the code at the moment.

You might find replacing functionality is not practical.

In which case consider porting your code rather than just using the assistant. You can create a .net 6 web app and add into that.

These are "just" dll and you can add specific dll to a project manually if necessary.

First find where your .net 6 framework dll are located on disk.

In your solution explorer, right click the project. Choose any of the add.. reference options.  Click browse and find your dll on disk.  System.Windows.Forms is a namespace.  You might have to check what the dll are actually called in msdn or by creating a scratch winforms app and looking at what you get in the bin when you compile.